# gdb displays not all variables in KDevelop

Tags: debugging, c++, gdb, g++, kdevelop

Hoping, the image describes the issue much better than I can do.

Generally, I'm debugging a multithreaded application in **KDevelop** with **gdb**.

I'm debugging the app step by step (F11 shortcut) and have already passed, say, the initialization of the variable ***resp***.

To the left of the screen is the list of all variables I'm able to see.

I'm using **-g** option for **g++**, but I suspect I'm missing some other options for it.

From my makefile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -ggdb -O example.cpp -I../libs -I$(BOOST_INCLUDES) -L$(BOOST_LIBS) -pthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system  -o example
```

So, basically, there are no problems with building the app. It is also running okay. Does anybody know why not all variables are displayed in the debugger?

[image]

Comment: Post [sufficient compilable code to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And given that this is a programming question, you should ask on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) explains this:

> GCC allows you to use `-g` with `-O`. The shortcuts taken by optimized code may occasionally produce surprising results: some variables you declared may not exist at all; flow of control may briefly move where you did not expect it; some statements may not be executed because they compute constant results or their values are already at hand; some statements may execute in different places because they have been moved out of loops.

In your case the variables you can't see while debugging were probably optimised away.

To debug your program, you [should use `-Og`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) instead of `-O` in your `g++` command line. This enables optimisations that don't have any effect on debugging.